# C# reference to loop variable

Tags: c#, reference

Is it possible in C# to something like the following

```
foreach (ref string var in arr) {
    var = "new value";
}
```

so that var variable was treated as reference and assigning to var would change an array element?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no such construct for **updating** a loop; an iterator is read-only. For example, the following provides a perfectly valid iterator:

```
public IEnumerable<int> Get1Thru5() {
    yield return 1; yield return 2; yield return 3;
    yield return 4; yield return 5;
}
```

How would it update? **What** would it update?

If the data is an array/list/etc, then something like:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.Length ; i++) {
    arr[i] = "new value";
}
```

Or other options depending on the specific container.

---

Update; at a **push**, an extension method:

```
public static void UpdateAll<T>(this IList<T> list, Func<T, T> operation) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
        list[i] = operation(list[i]);
    }
}
static void Main() {
    string[] arr = { "abc", "def", "ghi" };
    arr.UpdateAll(s => "new value");
    foreach (string s in arr) Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: You may even want to put `return list;` at the end of your **UpdateAll** extension method so that it can be chained and/or returned if it's used directly in an assignment such as `List<string> words = someWords.UpdateAll( s => s.Trim() );`.

Answer (score 2):

No. The `foreach` statement is simply syntax sugar on top of the [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) interface. This interface defines a method to get en [`IEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx) which in turn has methods to do *read-only* enumeration:

- Current : object
- MoveNext() : bool
- Reset() : void

Comment: *strictly* speaking it doesn't even need IEnumerable/IEnumerator, and it never uses Reset() - but indeed (+1)

Comment: And if you're using an array, it doesn't use IEnumerable at all.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach(string s in strings)
{
  Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

is compiler shortcut for:

```
IEnumerator e = strings.GetEnumerator();
string s;
while(e.MoveNext())
{
  s = e.Current;
  Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Since IEnumerator.Current is a get-only property you can't set the value.

```
// Non-generic IEnumerator shown.
interface IEnumerator
{
  bool MoveNext();
  object Current { get; }
  void Reset();
}
```

If you want to support an updatable enumerator you will need to create it yourself -- but you won't be able to use "foreach" with it, and you'll have to implement wrappers around all the common IEnumerable classes.

You'll have to analyze your current situation and figure out how to update.  If you're using an IList interface you can do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < strings.Count; ++i)
{
  string s = strings[i];
  //do work
  s = s.ToUpperInvariant();
  strings[i] = s;
}
```

Comment: Actually, the "string s" is **outside** the loop; this is important to understand the infamous foreach/capture issue. And it will use `Dispose()` if IDisposable is implemented

Comment: Was more for demonstration than accuracy, but you're right, @Marc Gravell.  I've moved the string outsid eof the loop.  Leaving Dispose() as an exercise to the reader as it's orthoganol to this discussion.

Answer (score 1):

> In the case of a string, no; C#
>   strings are immutable (cannot be
>   changed). If you were enumerating over
>   objects of a different, mutable type,
>   you can change the properties of those
>   objects.

Just to illustrate what Jacob is talking about. Consider the code snippet below:

```
class MyInt
{
    public int Val { get; set; }
    public MyInt(int val) { this.Val = val; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyInt[] array = new MyInt[] { new MyInt(1), new MyInt(2) };

        foreach (var obj in array) Console.Write("{0}\t", obj.Val);

        foreach (var obj in array)
        { 
            obj = new MyInt(100); // This doesn't compile! the reference is read only
            obj.Val *= 10; // This works just fine!
        }

        foreach (var obj in array) Console.Write("{0}\t", obj.Val);
    }
}
```

Indeed, if you try to assign to the "obj" as above you'll get a compile time error. But nothing prevents you from modifying MyInt's properties through the "obj" reference

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a string, no; C# strings are immutable (cannot be changed).  If you were enumerating over objects of a different, mutable type, you can change the properties of those objects.